# MUI Autocomplete, scroll with keyboard need highlight

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the Autocomplete component in MUI.  When scrolling through the options list using the keyboard, there is no visual indicator as to which row of options you are on.  Without this, using keyboard is not very useful.
For example if you type a few letters into the Autocomplete textfield it may show several options in the filtered list.  It would be nice to use the down arrow on the keyboard to select the desired option and press enter.   You can do all of that, but without a highlight you have no idea which row you are on before pressing the enter key.  Therefore, using the mouse to select is required.  Which makes data entry slower.
Is there something built in that I missed to enable this or is there some CSS override I can implement to have this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see a highlight in the demos: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete. Perhaps you have some global styles that are impacting the look.

Comment: Really?  When I try the demo on the URL you suggested.  I don't see a highlight.  I have 2 monitors and tried it on both.  Is the highlight very light or something, I don't see anything when I cursor up and down the drop down selections.

Comment: It's fairly light, but not so light that I would expect it to be hard to see on other monitors. The highlight does seem to be more pronounced in v5 though. See if you can see it there: https://next.material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#main-content.

Comment: In v4, they use the same styling for both the mouse hover effect and keyboard focus -- a background of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)`. In v5, the mouse hover effect is the same, but keyboard focus has a darker background of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)`.

Comment: Yes, in V5 I can see the highlight on the demos.  But V5 is not official yet, right?  Can I easily edit the CSS in V4 to make it darker?

Comment: v5's "official" stable release will most likely be within the next couple weeks. [5.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc.1) is the second release candidate.

Comment: In v4, the styling is targeted via a `data-focus` attribute: `.MuiAutocomplete-option[data-focus="true"] { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04); }`, but that controls the styling of both keyboard focus and mouse hover, so if you customize that, it will affect both.

Comment: Ok.  I can try that.  I was looking on github to figure out where to target the css, but wasn't finding where that was defined.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The default focus styles for v4 Autocomplete can be found here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L213.

Here's the relevant portion:

```
option: {
    '&[data-focus="true"]': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    }
}
```

Here's an example of customizing it using `withStyles`:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MuiAutocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Autocomplete = withStyles({
  option: {
    '&[data-focus="true"]': {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"
    }
  }
})(MuiAutocomplete);
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Customize Autocomplete focus color]

You can also customize this via the theme:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      option: {
        '&[data-focus="true"]': {
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Customize Autocomplete focus color]

The examples above change both the hover and focus styling (controlled by the same `data-focus` attribute in v4) to be a little darker.

In v5 the focus styling is handled differently and is darker for keyboard focus than for hover focus.

Comment: Ok.  Great response!  I appreciate the detail.  FYI, I'm using the import:  import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";   So I used const AutocompleteCustom = withStyles({
  option: {
    '&[data-focus="true"]': {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
    },
  },
})(Autocomplete);  Instead.  I can't seem to create a new line here in the comment.  So looks a bit messy.  Is there any difference?  or a reason you are using the lab version?

Comment: Your import is using the exact same lab version as mine -- you just chose a different variable name (`Autocomplete` instead of `MuiAutocomplete`). I simply chose a different name in the import so that I could use the standard name for the custom version returned by `withStyles` and leave the rest of the code from the demo unchanged.